# How to use React component's custom hook with "map"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

I'm trying to make a `Checkbox` component.

Here is my `Checkbox.tsx`.

```
import React from "react";
import * as S from "./style";

const Checkbox: React.FC<S.ICheckboxProps> = ({ checked, setChecked }) => {
  return <S.StyledCheckbox checked={checked} onClick={setChecked} />;
};
```

and this is my `useCheckbox.tsx`,

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useCheckbox = (initialState: boolean) => {
  const [checked, _setChecked] = useState<boolean>(initialState);
  const setCheckedToggle = () => _setChecked((prev) => !prev);
  const setCheckedTrue = () => _setChecked(true);
  const setCheckedFalse = () => _setChecked(false);
  return { checked, setCheckedToggle, setCheckedTrue, setCheckedFalse };
};

export default Checkbox;
```

It works good. I can use this like

```
import Layout from "components/Layout";
import { useCheckbox } from "hooks/useCheckbox";
import Checkbox from "components/Checkbox";

const Home = () => {
  const { checked, setCheckedToggle } = useCheckbox(false);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Checkbox checked={checked} setChecked={setCheckedToggle} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

But I have trouble in the `List` component.

`List` has a `Checkbox` component, and I have to use this `List` with `data`.

```
const Home = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {data.map((d) => <List />)}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

In this case, is there a way to determine if the list is selected?

If the `List` has `useCheckbox`, the `Home` component doesn't know the `checked` state.

Should I use `useCheckbox` in the `Home` component for `data.length` times? I think this is not good.

Thanks for reading, and Happy new year.

Comment: Why you have 2 components named the same ? - Your code is good but you need to check if the data actually exists before using it on a map() function. something like data.length > 0 && data.map()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the checkbox state to exist at the level of `Home` then you'll need state in the `Home` component that can handle multiple items, either as an array or object.

Then where you map over `data` you can pass down `checked` and `setChecked` as props to `List`, with all the logic defined in `Home` using the item index (or preferably an ID if you have one) in relation to your `Home` state.

Here's an example of a hook you could use in `Home`

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export const useCheckboxes = () => {
  const [checkedIds, setCheckedIds] = useState([]);

  const addToChecked = (id) => setCheckedIds((prev) => [...prev, id]);

  const removeFromChecked = (id) =>
    setCheckedIds((prev) => prev.filter((existingId) => existingId !== id));

  const isChecked = (id) => !!checkedIds.find(id);

  const toggleChecked = (id) =>
    isChecked(id) ? removeFromChecked(id) : addToChecked(id);

  return { isChecked, toggleChecked };
};
```

And you would use it like this

```
const Home = ({ data }) => {
  const { isChecked, toggleChecked } = useCheckboxes();

  return (
    <Layout>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <List
          key={d.id}
          checked={isChecked(d.id)}
          toggleChecked={() => toggleChecked(d.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```